# Can we track emails which is being sent with Flow Send Email

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a requirement to send emails from Opportunity object and track those emails on Account Activity history. I know that we can track emails by using Apex

```
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
        mail.setWhatId(inpFlow[0].whatID);
```

But Can we track emails that are being sent with Flow Send Email without using Apex?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to create a task on the opportunity and save it with the email details.